# Getting OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

I try to use [osm-bundler](https://code.google.com/archive/p/osm-bundler/downloads):

```
ubuntu: ~/osm-bundler$ ./RunBundler.py —photos="/home/ubuntu/photo"
Working directory created: /home/ubuntu/osm-bundler/output/osm-bundler-o1drFG
BundlerMatching executable path: /home/ubuntu/osm-bundler/software/bundler/KeyMatchFull
Sift executable path: /home/ubuntu/osm-bundler/software/sift-lowe/sift
```

but i get an error:

```
Processing photo 'IMGP3417.jpg':
Copy of the photo has been scaled down to 1200x900
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./RunBundler.py", line 10, in <module>
manager.preparePhotos()
File "/home/ubuntu/osm-bundler/osmbundler/__init__.py", line 168, in preparePhotos
self._preparePhoto(photoInfo)
File "/home/ubuntu/osm-bundler/osmbundler/__init__.py", line 278, in _preparePhoto
self.extractFeatures(photo)
File "/home/ubuntu/osm-bundler/osmbundler/__init__.py", line 345, in extractFeatures
self.featureExtractor.extract(photo, self.photoDict[photo])
File "/home/ubuntu/osm-bundler/osmbundler/features/siftlowe.py", line 25, in extract
p = subprocess.call(self.executable, **dict(stdin=photoFile, stdout=siftTextFile))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Lines 23,24, & 25 of `siftlowe.py`:

```
photoFile = open("%s.jpg.pgm" % photo, "rb")
siftTextFile = open("%s.key" % photo, "w")
subprocess.call(self.executable, **dict(stdin=photoFile, stdout=siftTextFile))
```

File permissions are set correctly.

Comment: that's because `self.executable` does not exist. Can you print it?

Comment: Yes, i can print it (/home/ubuntu/osm-bundler/software/sift-lowe/sift)

Comment: I think the answer below solves your problem. Can you confirm that / accept the answer if works?

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but it doesn't work in my case unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did only install `osm-bundler.zip` and not `osm-budler-full.zip`. The line with the `self.executable` tries to execute sift, which is expected at `/home/ubuntu/osm-bundler/software/sift-lowe/sift`. This is most probably not installed (I tried it myself with `osm-bundler.zip` and this was missing).

Comment: Thank you.
Now I installed osm-bundler-full.zip. The path for the sift file is /home/ubuntu/osm-bundler/software/sift-lowe/sift ….but the error is the same

Comment: @Ian can you copy-paste the command you call with the full output into gist.github.com and add the link here?